# HTTP access to on-going Jenkins build files

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I guess the title is pretty self-explanatory. The reason I want that is so that I can make a live custom HTML reporter for my tests.

My test suite takes hours to complete, and although the tests generate HTML reports as soon as each test step is executed, it's only at post-build time that those report files get published.

Being able to see them as they get generated would reduce the time it takes for me and my teammates to analyze and act upon issues revealed by our test runs.

All I need is that Jenkins let me access the build files as the build executes. Nothing fancy; I can take care of the rest. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

In our setup there is always an intermediate file (typically XML) but the HTML files are created at the end of the job.

What you can do, is use the progressive output (http://jenkins/job/jobName/buildNumber/logText/progressiveText?start=0).  Although you don't state which framework you use, most of them output something that would be easy to parse.  e.g. "Test xxx failed".

Comment: Hi, Allan. Thanks for your response. We do have a progressive view of the logs as they are written, but I really need access to the files I'm generating on-the-fly as the build runs :(

Comment: Assuming that you have a master/slave setup, that's tricky because I believe that all artifacts are only copied back to the master at the end of the job.  This would mean that you would have to setup some sort of HTTP server (or other) on each slave to serve the files (which almost certainly exist in the slave's workspace).  With our configuration, we have one executor per slave - although it feels quite hacky, I would be tempted to add another slave instance to the same server with a different label - you could then run an another job on a scheduled basis to grab the files.

Comment: Using [Jenkins Workflow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin) you will be able to archive artifacts at any moment of your build.